# How to get the current player's leaderboard score in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I need to increment the current player's leaderboard score.  In order to do this in java, I did something like this:

```
PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult> result = Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,  getString(R.string.winsleaderboardid), LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC);

if(result != null)
{
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult loadPlayerScoreResult) {
            if(loadPlayerScoreResult != null && loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore() != null)
            {
                Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.winsleaderboardid), loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore() + 1);
            }
            else
            {                                 
                Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.winsleaderboardid), 1);
            }
        }
   });
}
```

I can't seem to find the interface for ILoadPlayerScoreResult in Xamarin but I expected something like:

```
private async void IncrementLeaderBoardWins()
    {
        IResult result = await GamesClass.Leaderboards.LoadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(
                    mGoogleApiClient, GetString(Resource.String.winsleaderboardid), Android.Gms.Games.LeaderBoard.LeaderboardVariant.TimeSpanAllTime,
                    Android.Gms.Games.LeaderBoard.LeaderboardVariant.CollectionPublic);

        OnResult(result);
    }

public void OnResult(ILoadPlayerScoreResult loadPlayerScoreResult)
{
    if (loadPlayerScoreResult != null && loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore() != null)
    {
        GamesClass.Leaderboards.SubmitScore(mGoogleApiClient, GetString(Resource.String.winsleaderboardid), loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore() + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        GamesClass.Leaderboards.SubmitScore(mGoogleApiClient, GetString(Resource.String.winsleaderboardid), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LoadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScoreAsync` to return an `ILeaderboardsLoadPlayerScoreResult` vs. `LoadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore` that returns an `IResult` that you need to await and cast.

#### Quick Example:

```
var myGamerID = "StackOverflowGamer";
var score = 9999;
var client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).AddApi(GamesClass.API).AddScope(GamesClass.ScopeGames).Build();
client.BlockingConnect();
var result = await GamesClass.Leaderboards.LoadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScoreAsync(client, "StackOverflowLeaderBoard", LeaderboardVariant.TimeSpanAllTime, LeaderboardVariant.CollectionPublic);
Console.WriteLine(result.Score);
GamesClass.Leaderboards.SubmitScore(client, myGamerID, score);
```

Comment: I don't understand.  IPlayersLoadPlayersResult Doesn't seem to define a Score() method or a Score property.  It just has a 'PlayerBuffer' object which seems like just a list of java.lang.Object

Comment: Did you mean ILeaderboardLoadPlayerScoreResult ?

Comment: Use `LoadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScoreAsync` that returns a `ILeaderboardsLoadPlayerScoreResult`

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for - was just confused about your first bullet where you mentioned 'IPlayersLoadPlayersResult'

Comment: @b15 Ah, when you said you were looking for `ILoadPlayerScoreResult`, I *assumed* you meant `IPlayersLoadPlayersResult`... I'll remove that bullet point ;-)

Comment: Is there any good documentation on the Xamarin specific google api libraries?  Sometimes guessing around for the new Classes/Interfaces/Enums can be awful.

Comment: @b15 I WISH! lol.... I use the `source` **a lot** when first learning (& guessing) where the Classes/Interface/Enums have been "moved" to in the C# renaming convention as that ***convention*** gets messy with the Google APIs/packages when moving from Java to C# and the C# variant of the Java class name has been renamed (WHY, WHY, WHY,,,,lmao, there are real reasons it is done )... so I do searches like this : https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/search?utf8=✓&q=ILeaderboardsLoadPlayerScoreResult and `grep` the local repo clone using wildcards `*LoadPlayerScore*`.

Comment: @b15 Also using the Android binding **Transforms** is as great way to find the Java to C# renames, i.e.: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/firebase-analytics/source/Transforms